# Cats Blender Plugin Tab Not Showing

Tags: add-on

I recently added a plug-in for Blender which is the Cats Blender Tab.

However, once I enabled the plugin, it isn't showing on the left tab.

[image]
I did check to make sure it was enabled and it was, however it isn't displaying the tab.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: It might be that is not supposed to be in the tab to the left. Maybe look elsewhere in the UI?

Comment: It should show up once the addon is enabled. What version of blender? What version of cats plugin?